# Read and write to TCP socket in Java

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I am creating a simple TCP server in java which accepts clients. Each client that connects to the server sends a message, and sends an answer based on the message.

In order to accept clients I am using `ServerSocket` class. In order to read the client's message and write to him I am allowed to use only in the `Socket`, `DataOutputStream` and `DataInputStream` classes and in `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`. In addition, every message that the server gets and sends must be in UTF-8 encoding.

However, I am not sure how to read and write messages in UTF-8 encoding using those classes. The size of the messages is unbounded. I tried to read about the `read` function of `DataInputStream` class, but I couldn't understand how to use it (if this indeed the function I need to use).

Answer (score 1):

`DataOutputStream` has a `writeUTF()` method, and `DataInputStream` has a `readUTF()` method. Just note that these methods deal in [**modified** UTF-8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#modified-utf-8) rather than **standard** UTF-8, and they limit the UTF-8 data to 65535 bytes max.

To provide interoperability with non-Java clients, and/or handle longer strings, would be better to just handle the UTF-8 yourself manually.

The sender can use `String.getBytes()` to encode a `String` to a `byte[]` array using `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`, then send the array's length using `DataOutputStream.writeInt()`, and then finally send the actual bytes using `DataOutputStream.write(byte[])`.

The receiver can then read the array length using `DataInputStream.readInt()`, then allocate a `byte[]` array and read it using `DataInputStream.readFully()`, and then finally use the `String` constructor to decode the bytes using `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`.